# ASP.NET MVC 2 to MVC 4 converted project runs slower

Tags: .net, performance, asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently we have converted the ASP.NET MVC 2 project to ASP.NET MVC 4.

In MVC2 we had used LINQ to SQL. In MVC4 we are using Entity Framework. When comparing the loading speed MVC4 runs slower than MVC2.

I have compared a basic page that just pulls the list of Contacts and both are having the same functionality and flow (Controller -> BLL -> Repository(DAL)). But MVC4 loads slower than MVC2.

[image: Firebug of MVC2]
Above is screenshot of firebug from MVC2 application

[image: Firebug of MVC4]
Above is screenshot of firebug from MVC4 application

Both are the same functionality, but it differs in the time they load.

How to find the loading issue in my MVC4? Is there any tool that points out any issues/leakage? Please suggest.

**Update:**

When i checked the loading speed by commenting the call to Database and still had the same issue. When i comment the Dependency Injection, it runs normal. When i use the Controller without any Interfaces like below, it loads faster:

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    public UserController()
    {
    }
}
```

But When i use the Interfaces(Dependency Injection) as below, it takes longer time:

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    private IUserService _userService;
    private IPaymentService _paymentService;
    private ICommonService _commonService;
    private IAdminService _adminService;
    private IAUserService _adminUserService;

    public UserController()
    {
    }

    public UserController(IUserService userService, IPaymentService paymentService, ICommonService commonService, IAdminService adminService, IAUserService adminUserService)
    {
        this._userService = userService;
        this._paymentService = paymentService;
        this._commonService = commonService;
        this._adminService = adminService;
        this._adminUserService = adminUserService;
    }
}
```

I have posted a thread at [ASP.NET forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/1785359/4899828.aspx/1?RE%20Performance%20issue%20after%20upgrading%20MVC2%20from%20L2S%20to%20EF), which gave me the idea to check by removing the Dependency Injection.

Also in Scott Gu's [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/02/19/asp-net-mvc-4-beta.aspx), but no positive response so far.

Its something fishy with the Dependency Injection, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The slowness can be caused by many reasons like first time caching in MVC, EF schema creation. 
You should first figure out which part makes the response slow. The easiest and efficient way is to use trace code like Stopwatch. Set checkpoint at request start, action start, db access start, db access end, action end, and request end.

If it's just the first time load slow, it's probably not a critical issue. MVC will caches data like controller, action, view search path or model metadata which will accelerate subsequent requests processing.

Comment: Hongye, Thanks for the Response. It runs slower even when i run it for the 2nd, 3rd times. Even i checked it my commenting the call to Database and still had the same issue. I have updated my question with the updates

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with MVC 3?  Since MVC4 is in beta, there could be performance issues.

Comment: I have converted the MVC4 application to MVC3, but still had the same issue.

Comment: Please read the performance comparison of MVC2 with MVC3 at [Marcin's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/17/mvc-3-performance.aspx).  Marcin says the DI could be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I just read the Blog, Marcin says there's a performance issue due to DI, but sadly there is no solution for DI performance issue in that Blog